# SUBSTRING_INDEX equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Table:

```
id | name    
1  | a,b,c    
2  | b
```

Output

```
id | name    
1  | a    
1  | b    
1  | c    
2  | b
```

I found this query online and it works fine in mySql Phpmyadmin query editor.

```
SELECT
  tablename.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX (tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', - 1) NAME
FROM  (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4) numbers
INNER JOIN tablename
    ON CHAR_LENGTH (tablename.name) - CHAR_LENGTH (REPLACE (tablename.name, ',', '')) >= numbers.n - 1
ORDER BY id, n
```

But in SQL Server, it throws

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'SUBSTRING_INDEX' is not a recognized built-in function name.
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'numbers'.
```

Edit: This query uses in tableau development, Where TSQL is not working as expecting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YePr8.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server equivalent of substring\_index function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854724/sql-server-equivalent-of-substring-index-function-in-mysql)

Comment: Sorry.This is a different case though the heading is similar

Comment: MySQL and TSQL are different dialects of SQL Apparently you need to translate your MySQL query to TSQL - something you did not make apparent. But you would not have this problem with a properly normalized table - so maybe now is the time to fix your schema.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server 2016 and later, we can use `STRING_SPLIT` here:

```
SELECT id, value AS name  
FROM yourTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(name, ',')
ORDER BY id, value;
```

Comment: I replaced SUBSTRNG_INDEX with CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT. but that doesnt works. it throews [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CROSS'. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'numbers'.

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?  Maybe it is time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] INT
   ,[name] VARCHAR(24)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Name])
VALUES (1, 'a,b,c')
      ,(2, 'b');

WITH DataSource ([ID], [nameXML]) AS
(
    SELECT [ID]
          ,CAST('<a>' + REPLACE([name], ',', '</a><a>')+ '</a>' AS XML)
    FROM @DataSource
)

SELECT [ID]
      ,T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM DataSource DS
CROSS APPLY [nameXML].nodes('./a') T(c);
```

Comment: I wantee to execute the query in node express project with MSSQL database. So MSSQL query is required..

Comment: @RoopeshE It's `MSSQL` query, but better use `T-SQL` when referring the SQL dialect for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: K. But could you provide the equivalent of this tsql?

Comment: It is a valid T-SQL statement for sure. I have write it on my SSMS and execute it several times.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursive CTE as the following

```
CREATE TABLE TBL(
  Id INT,
  String VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT TBL VALUES
(1, 'a,b,c'),
(2, 'b');

WITH CTE(Id, Chr, String) AS
(
  SELECT Id,
         CAST(LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(20)),
         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
  FROM TBL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Id,
         CAST(LEFT(String, CHARINDEX(',', String + ',') - 1) AS VARCHAR(20)),
         STUFF(String, 1, CHARINDEX(',', String + ','), '')
  FROM CTE
  WHERE String > ''
)
SELECT Id,
       Chr
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Id;
```

[Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d23d95c25b048df1305486713a21ee93)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Bt I updated my question. The TSQL is not solution in this case. Because i need to put the querry in tableau development as well. There its not working.

Comment: @RoopeshE So why you tag SQL Server in the first place?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. i couldnt find mssql tag name. Also the database is accessing via sql server... And the usual query works in sql server.