# Computed Column on Split Value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, substring, sql-server-2022

Using SQL Server 2022, attempt to create a computed column for indexing/queries on the 3rd part of a string separated by slashes (it's a URI).

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
    ADD SpotName AS (CAST((SELECT Value FROM STRING_SPLIT(FullUri, '/', 7)) AS VarChar(128))) PERSISTED
```

And the error I get is:

> Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

I want to do this for 5 different parts of URIs, so what is a smart way to index/optimize queries for different substring parts?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't do that because `String_Split()` returns multiple row. What are you trying to achieve here ? Please do include some sample data and expected result

Comment: You can put your sub-query into a function... can't speak for its performance... well I can, it will be rubbish... but if thats what you need.

Comment: `String_Split(FullUri,'/',7)` You should be getting error on the `enable_ordinal` value, it does allow value other than null, 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
Alter Table MyTable 
Add SpotName As (  Cast(JSON_VALUE('["' + REPLACE(FullUri, '/', '","') + '"]', '$[6]')as VarChar(128))) PERSISTED
```

To split the string in a manner that is regarded as deterministic so can be persisted and/or indexed and without using Scalar UDFs (that [block parallelism on the table by default](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187370/3690)).

Note the position is `0` based - not `1` based. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KnNRxxso)

Comment: Please consider contributing this outstanding answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854724/sql-server-equivalent-of-substring-index-function-in-mysql as well.

Comment: @O.Jones - that's tagged 2012.  The `JSON_VALUE` approach requires at least 2016

Comment: Right you are, but still...