# SQL to remove text from the left hand side of the fourth special character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can’t quite find the correct combination of function(s) to remove all text from the left hand side of the fourth special character ‘\’.

I have the following string…

```
pw:\\abcdef-uk-ldn-pw.acme.com:abcdef-uk-ldn-pw-02\Documents\_Demonstration\PROJ1_JAC\30 Project Data\A - Architecture\03 - Documents\PROJ1_JAC-JAC-XX-00-D-A-0001
```

…and I’d like to remove everything to the left of the 4th ‘\’ such that I’m left with

```
_Demonstration\PROJ1_JAC\30 Project Data\A - Architecture\03 - Documents\PROJ1_JAC-JAC-XX-00-D-A-0001
```

I can see a function in MySQL (SUBSTRING_INDEX()) but can’t see an equivalent in SQL Server.

Comment: see: [SQL Server equivalent of substring_index function in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854724/sql-server-equivalent-of-substring-index-function-in-mysql)

Comment: What version of SQL Server? In SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL DB / MI [this is simple](https://dbfiddle.uk/5K192S3-).

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to treat your delimited string as a json *array*, you can simply then filter on the array element position and aggregate:

```
with t as (
    select string = 'pw:\\abcdef-uk-ldn-pw.acme.com:abcdef-uk-ldn-pw-02\Documents\_Demonstration\PROJ1_JAC\30 Project Data\A - Architecture\03 - Documents\PROJ1_JAC-JAC-XX-00-D-A-0001'
)
select String_Agg(value, '\') within group(order by j.[key])
from t
cross apply OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(string, '\', '","'),'"]'))j
where j.[key] >= 4;
```

Comment: Just be careful of edge cases (like `string` contains `"`).

Answer (score 0):

On 2022+, you could just use `STRING_SPLIT` and `STRING_AGG` while limiting the results from `STRING_SPLIT` to the 5th delimited value onwards:

```sql
DECLARE @YourString varchar(MAX) = 'pw:\\abcdef-uk-ldn-pw.acme.com:abcdef-uk-ldn-pw-02\Documents\_Demonstration\PROJ1_JAC\30 Project Data\A - Architecture\03 - Documents\PROJ1_JAC-JAC-XX-00-D-A-0001'

SELECT STRING_AGG(SS.value,'\') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY SS.ordinal)
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourString,'\',1) SS
WHERE SS.ordinal >= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this [Substring_Index() in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854724/sql-server-equivalent-of-substring-index-function-in-mysql/76879926#76879926) you could write something like:

```
declare @str varchar(MAX) = 
  'pw:\\abcdef-uk-ldn-pw.acme.com:abcdef-uk-ldn-pw-02\Documents\'
 +'_Demonstration\PROJ1_JAC\30 Project Data\A - Architecture\03 '
 +'- Documents\PROJ1_JAC-JAC-XX-00-D-A-0001'
select dbo.Substring_Index(@str, dbo.Substring_Index(@str, '\', 4) + '\', -1)
```